# firemonkey android fullscreen with statusbar

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

how can i design my ui like the provided image

[image]

this is full screen and have status bar.
when i put full screen as true it hide the status bar

[image]

i also put status bar `visibility` as `visibale` or `VisibleAndOverlap` and select a color but it dont look like my sent image !!

[image]

is this kind of desgn available in firemonkey !?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by updating the default style. you must update the AndroidManifest.template.xml by somethink like

```
<application android:persistent="%persistent%" 
             android:restoreAnyVersion="%restoreAnyVersion%" 
             android:label="%label%" 
             android:debuggable="%debuggable%" 
             android:largeHeap="%largeHeap%"
             android:icon="%icon%"
             android:theme="@style/myAppTheme"
             android:hardwareAccelerated="%hardwareAccelerated%">
```

and then you must provide a style.xml with the setting you need (like make the statusbar translucent)

exemple of style.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <style name="myAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff2b2e38</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff0288d1</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ff0087b4</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

see exemple of a demo app that override the default style at https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe (demo is alfmxcontrols)

Comment: i tried to install alcinoe times and times,but i cant install it yet :|

Comment: @zeus Your solution is to make the system bars translucent (semi transparent) and for that it works perfectly, but not to make the system bars background full transparent as the screenshot. I made a tutorial of the complete solution to set the status bar and navigation bar full transparent background, including in the splash screen and also setting the brightness of the system bars foreground and teaching how to predict the size of the system bars to padding in form.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the status bar and navigation bar background transparent with my code in github:

https://github.com/viniciusfbb/fmx_tutorials/tree/master/delphi_system_bars/

In this case you need to use:

```
uses
  iPub.FMX.SystemBars;

  ...

  Form1.SystemBars.StatusBarBackgroundColor := TAlphaColors.Null;
  Form1.SystemBars.NavigationBarBackgroundColor := TAlphaColors.Null;
  Form1.SystemBars.Visibility := TipFormSystemBars.TVisibilityMode.VisibleAndOverlap;
```